# Give focus to text-entry field in prompt in node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

In most browsers, a javascript prompt() gives focus to the text entry field so the user can begin typing immediately.

In node-webkit, a javascript prompt() gives focus to the prompt *window*, but not the text entry field. The user has to click inside the field before typing.

How can I set the focus to inside the text entry field when using a prompt in node-webkit?

Comment: Keep an eye on https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/1123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extensible way is to create your own prompts with a javascript modal window.  Many of the common JS frameworks have easy ways of creating a modal window which will give you complete control over the text and inputs being displayed.